# Largest prime factor of a Mersenne number with exactly two prime divisors

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

For a prime $p$, let $M_p = 2^p-1$ be a (Mersenne) number with exactly two prime divisors, and let $P(p)$ be the largest of these two. Clearly $P(p) > \sqrt{M_p}$. This is very likely a hard question, but can we say anything about how far $P(p)$ is from $\sqrt{M_p}$? For instance, could it possibly be true that the ratio
$$
R(p) = \dfrac{P(p)}{\sqrt{M_p}}
$$
is unbounded?

Murata and Pomerance conjectured in

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/murata4.pdf

that $P(p)$ grows asymptotically faster than any polynomial in $p$. But this is still under $\sqrt{M_p}$, not useful in our case of $P(p) >\sqrt{M_p} $ with $M_p$ having two prime factors.

Given that all the prime factors of $M_p$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $2p$, one initial idea could be to get an asymptotic expression for the smallest prime greater than $\sqrt{M_p}$ and which is congruent to $1$ modulo $2p$. Can this be feasible? Or perhaps there is another way to go about this, if any at all? Thank you very much.

Here's some data. The pairs are $(p, R(p))$ for which $M_p$ has exactly two prime divisors. Notice the large values of $R(p)$ towards the end. Although there are some proportionally smaller ones, as the ones for $p = 11, 101, 137, 149$. But even here $R(p) > p^{1/4}$. Curiously, these last primes $p$ are also the first entries of twin prime pairs (what??).

(11, 1.9671210479762813)
(23, 61.623600066097914)
(37, 1662.455605799928)
(41, 110.9381611714366)
(59, 4219.204811276472)
(67, 62.713050038434965)
(83, 18622086898.05674)
(97, 34774677167.19322)
(101, 214.23442518117758)
(103, 1248743.6542854793)
(109, 34150923.513927594)
(131, 1.9838506198224765e+17)
(137, 13.03069933308962)
(139, 148389420.30816036)
(149, 308.27243485390295)
(167, 5.82260553430773e+18)
(197, 5.986138210208216e+25)
(199, 5.448860357248897e+18)
(227, 5.4420261679031904e+17)
(241, 8.5444423288905e+28)
(269, 2.2282001358749983e+33)
(271, 4.041186699015196e+30)

Comment: I suspect such things will be very hard to prove; but the contrary statement, that $P(p)/\sqrt{M_p}$ is bounded, would be a massively surprising turn of events.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I took the liberty to add some data quite some time after the original post. The pattern, if there is one, about the twin primes, is a bit intriguing..

Comment: I recommend not getting too excited ... law of small numbers....

Comment: :) It would be nice to have a faster computer and check this for higher twin primes, but mine is not up to the task. It would be very nice if someone could compute this a bit more. Even nicer would if such a list of factors of (small but not too small) Mersenne numbers is known..